# Get related array from another table by foreign key

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper-5

I'm using SQL Server 2012, MVC WebAPI, AutoMapper and Entity Framework.
In the database I have two tables with one-to-many relation, for example Categories and Products; a category can have more products but a product can have only one category. What I want is a json that for each category contains also an array of related products by Products.CategoryId field.

This is what I made after some search in internet:

```
public class CategoriesViewModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductsViewModel> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class ViewModelMapper
{
    public static TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TDestination>(source);
    }

    public static void RegisterMaps()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<Products, ProductsViewModel>().ReverseMap();
            config.CreateMap<Categories, CategoriesViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Products, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Products))
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}

// Repository
public IEnumerable<CategoriesViewModel> GetCategories()
{
    return ViewModelMapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoriesViewModel>>(Context.Categories);
}

//Business Logic
public IEnumerable<CategoriesViewModel> GetCategories()
{
    return Repository.GetCategories();
}

[Route("Categories"), HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetCategories()
{
    return Ok(BL.GetCategories());
}
```

My result is a list of Categories with and empty or null Products array and I cannot find a solution.

How can I reach my result?
Thank you

**EDIT:**

Entity Framework Models

```
public partial class Category
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Category and Product are only examples, ignore if the view model property names are not the same.

Comment: Can we see the models?

Comment: I think that there is a misunderstanding with class names. Classes as CategoriesViewModel are Models. I don't have any other type of code: CategoriesRepository gets data from database by EF and returns mapped CategoriesViewModel.

Comment: No, they are the ViewModels and are irrelevant to the issue. I need the entity models, i.e. `Categories` and `Products` classes.

Comment: Do you mean EF generated classes? I added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have [Lazy Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx) off.

So one solution would be to turn it on, but I would not suggest it, because it would execute many database queries.

A better option would be to use [Eager Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx):

```
return ViewModelMapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoriesViewModel>>(
    Context.Categories.Include(c => c.Products));
```

or

```
return ViewModelMapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoriesViewModel>>(
    Context.Categories.Include("Products"));
```

But the best option with AutoMapper is to use `ProjectTo` method from [`QueryableExtensions`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions):

```
retirn Context.Categories.ProjectTo<CategoriesViewModel>();
```

for the reasons explained in the link.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some feedback, like does the answer helped resolving the issue or not etc.

Comment: Sure, sorry but I've just tested it now at work. It works great the suggestions with AutoMapper extension for Entity Framework! ;) In my real case I had also some mapping problem with nullable properties so I fixed them. Thank you very much.